# How to set kate's vi mode to show absolute line numbers?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, kate, plasma-5

I've started using Plasma5 and I have an issue with Kate's Vi mode.
When showing the line numbers on the border it always shows *relative* line numbers instead of absolute ones, while this didn't happen in Kate with KDE4.

Is it possible to configure it to show absolute line numbers as in normal mode?

In the configuration pages I can only see the "show line numbers" options, but nothing about relative/absolute numbering. Is this simply missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that relative line numbers are available only with the Vi editing mode, and hence their settings are together with those of the Vi mode instead of being near the border settings.